# IE doesn't support function generators

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, syntax-error

I have a javascript code that uses function generator (`function*()`). As you know IE doesn't support these function and I use another way for IE especially and use such this code:

```
if (false || !!document.documentMode){  //IE browser
    //do for IE
}
else {
    function*(){
        //do for other browsers
    }
}
```

but in IE, the browser got syntax error and page doesn't work! I even used `try-catch` but didn't work.

how should I handle this problem?

thanks.

Comment: take a look at mdn and in support table, yes IT NOT SUPPORTED by IE https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/function*

Comment: It doesn't matter what type of block you put it in, it's still going to see `function*()` as a syntax error. You will have to separate it out to a file and only load that file for IE, or use `eval()`

Comment: Don't use `eval`.

Comment: if you MUST support IE, transpile

Comment: Or write IE-compatible code in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code in an `else` statement is still interpreted, even if it's not going to run on that browser.
This means it can not contain syntax errors.

For IE, `function*` *is* a syntax error.
A `try-catch` block doesn't catch syntax errors, because the code isn't executed if there are syntax errors.

Basically, if you want to support IE, that *file* can not contain `function*`

Comment: ok. this mean I don't have any way to handle this in IE? I can not separate this part of code to other file, because the functionality will miss.

Comment: You can just load the other file, depending on the user's browser. Or you write a different method that doesn't use a generator function, and just use that instead, for all browsers. (I mean, you have to write the IE fallback already, so why not use that everywhere?)

Comment: I decided to separate whole of functions in my project and write it in another .js file. although it is hard and complex coding, but helped. thank you.